# A man purchased some eggs at the rate of 10 units per dozen and again purchased $\frac{3}{4} $ of them at the rate of 12 units per dozen.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A man purchased some eggs at the rate of 10 units per dozen and again purchased $ \frac{3}{4} $ of them at the rate of 12 units per dozen. He sold all eggs at the rate of 13 units per dozen and made a profit of 30 units. Find the total number of eggs he purchased all together.

Options were:

1. 8 dozens
2. 9 dozens
3. 10 dozens
4. None of these

I think it should be 14 dozens and hence option 4 should be the answer. But the book says it is 8. It doesn't say why.

I think he must have purchased $ x $ dozens first and then $ \frac{3x}{4} $ dozens again.

After the simple calculation, the result comes out as 8, just like the book wants but what about the $ \frac{3x}{4} $?

Comment: You're right. If the book states that the correct answer is $8$, then the question is ill-phrased (at best). The total number of egg-dozens that the man purchased is indeed $8+\frac34\cdot8=14$.